# Netfabb Premium 2023 supported printer list

Tags: desktop-printer

Do anyone knows if Flashforge adventurer 3/4 are supported by Netfabb Premium 2023? I can not find a printer list.

Comment: Have you checked the support pages? Where have you already looked to eliminate duplicate work?

Comment: yes, can not find

Answer (score 1):

You have to search harder next time :)

https://help.autodesk.com/view/NETF/2023/ENU/?guid=GUID-87CA46ED-E590-45FC-93D2-B72A3EA68554

Comment: Welcome to 3D Printing! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.